# How is empty node tag in xml and non-existence of node interpreted?

Tags: xml, xsd, simplexml

I have two XML request:

```
<GetPersonRequest>
    <Person/>
    <IncludeAddress>true</IncludeAddress>
</GetPersonRequest>
```

and

```
<GetPersonRequest>
    <IncludeAddress>true</IncludeAddress>
</GetPersonRequest>
```

Is there a difference between empty nodes and non-existence of nodes ? Does the XML parser makes any difference ?. Does call to text of both node returns empty string ?

I would like to add that second XML is similar in that element is optional. So the user might just omit. Does xml.getElement("Person") still return null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These XMLs are different. 1st XML contains element `Person` (empty element, its `text()` is `null`), while 2nd doesn't. For 2nd XML (pseudo-code) `xml.getElement("Person")` will return `null`.